# Jekyll private deployment?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I have created jekyll site. Regarding the deployment I don't want to host on github pages. To host private domain I came know from documentation to copy the all files from _site folder. That's all wicked.

Question:

1. Each time I add new blog post, I am running cmd>jekyll build then I am copying newly created html to hosted domain. Is there any easy way to update without compiling each time ?
2. The reason, Why I am asking is because it will updated by non technical person

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use GitHub Pages, AFAIK there's no other way than to compile your site each time you make a change.

But of course you can script/automate as much as possible.
That's what I do with my own blog as well. I'm hosting it on my own webspace instead of GitHub Pages, so I need to do these steps for each update:

1. Compile on local machine
2. Upload via FTP

I can do this with a single click (okay, a single *double-click*).

---

*Note: I'm on Windows, so the following solution is for Windows.

But if you're using Linux/MacOS/whatever, of course you can use the tools given there to build something similar.*

---

I'm using a [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) *(the Windows equivalent to a [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script))* to compile my site and then call [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/), a free command-line FTP client.

WinSCP allows me to [store session configurations](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_configuration#site), so I saved the connection to my server there once.
Because of this, I didn't want to commit WinSCP to my *(public)* repository, so my script expects WinSCP in the parent folder.

The batch file looks like this:

```
call jekyll build

echo If the build succeeded, press RETURN to upload!

pause

set uploadpath=%~dp0\_site
%~dp0\..\winscp.com /script=build-upload.txt /xmllog=build-upload.log

pause
```

The first parameter in the WinSCP call (`/script=build-upload.txt`) specifies the [script file which contains the actual WinSCP commands](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#script_file)

This is in the script file:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off

open blog
synchronize remote -delete "%uploadpath%"

close
exit
```

Some explanations:

1. `%~dp0` *(in the batch file)* is the folder where the current batch file is
2. The `set uploadpath=...` line  *(in the batch file)* saves the complete path to the generated site into an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)
3. The `open blog` line *(in the script file)* opens a connection to the [pre-saved session configuration](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_configuration#site) (which I named `blog`)
4. The `synchronize remote ...` line *(in the script file)* uses the [`synchronize` command](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) to sync from the local folder *(saved in `%uploadpath%`, the environment variable from step 2)* to the server.

---

IMO this solution is suitable for non-technical persons as well.
If the technical person in your case doesn't know how to use source control, you could even script committing & pushing, too.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options available which are mentioned in the documentation: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/

If you are using Git, I would recommend the Git Post-Receive Hook approach. It simply builds the site after the new code is received:

```
GIT_REPO=$HOME/myrepo.git
TMP_GIT_CLONE=$HOME/tmp/myrepo
PUBLIC_WWW=/var/www/myrepo

git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
jekyll build -s $TMP_GIT_CLONE -d $PUBLIC_WWW
rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
exit
```

Since you mentioned that it will be updated by a non-technical person, you might try something like [`rack-jekyll`](https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll) to automatically rebuild when new files are FTP'd.