# Jekyll clobbering directory in _site despite _config.yml.

Tags: gulp, jekyll

I'm building a site with Jekyll and using Gulp to manage the assets. Since I'm using Gulp to manage my assets, I would like Jekyll to ignore ./assets in the conversion process and to leave ./_site/assets/ alone when building the rest of the site.

I've configured the _config.yml with

```
exclude: [assets] # Exclude assets/ from the conversion
keep: [assets]    # Don't delete _site/assets when building the site
```

My gulpfile.js is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass('assets/stylesheets/main.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.start('sass');
});
```

I then run:

```
gulp
jekyll build
```

When I run `gulp`, the ./_sites/assets/ directory is created as expected, but when I run `jekyll build` ./_site/assets/ is deleted. What configuration am I missing?

Comment: I think it is ```keep_files:``` not just ```keep```. Have you tried that?

Comment: Ron is right, keep_files should be correct. From jekyll's doc pages [http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) " Destination folders are cleaned on site builds The contents of <destination> are automatically cleaned, by default, when the site is built. Files or folders that are not created by your site will be removed. Some files could be retained by specifying them within the <keep_files> configuration directive. Do not use an important location for <destination>; instead, use it as a staging area and copy files from there to your web server."

Comment: Yep, my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As was noted before keep_files directive is correct, instead of just keep. Following information from Jekyll's site http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

> Destination folders are cleaned on site builds The contents of
>    are automatically cleaned, by default, when the site is
>   built. Files or folders that are not created by your site will be
>   removed. Some files could be retained by specifying them within the
>    configuration directive. Do not use an important location
>   for ; instead, use it as a staging area and copy files
>   from there to your web server.

I decided to check this by doing things from scratch step by step 
part that I appended to default jekyll's _config.yml file looks like this

```
exclude: [someFolderHere]  
keep_files: [someFolderHere]
```

> creating new jekyll site from scratch

wolf@sloth:~/blogs$ jekyll new dummy-blog
    New jekyll site installed in /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog. 
    wolf@sloth:~/blogs$ cd dummy-blog/
    wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$

> checking contents of site's folder

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll -rta
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 12 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  435 Jan 30 09:40 _config.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _layouts
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  451 Jan 30 09:40 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _includes
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 css
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _posts
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf 1292 Jan 30 09:40 feed.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  470 Jan 30 09:40 about.md
drwxr-xr-x  6 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 .
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> running first build

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ jekyll build
Configuration file: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_config.yml
            Source: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog
       Destination: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_site
      Generating... 
                    done.
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> checking contents of site's folder again

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll -rta
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 12 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  435 Jan 30 09:40 _config.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _layouts
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  451 Jan 30 09:40 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _includes
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 css
drwxr-xr-x  2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:40 _posts
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf 1292 Jan 30 09:40 feed.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 wolf wolf  470 Jan 30 09:40 about.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 _site
drwxr-xr-x  7 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 .
```

> now we have _site folder

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll _site/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 jekyll
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolf wolf 5816 Jan 30 09:41 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolf wolf 2954 Jan 30 09:41 feed.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 about
drwxr-xr-x 7 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 wolf wolf 4096 Jan 30 09:41 .
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> creating some folder under _site

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ mkdir _site/someFolderHere
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ touch _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> checking if this file is this there...

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123 
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolf wolf 0 Jan 30 09:42 _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> running build again

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ jekyll build
Configuration file: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_config.yml
            Source: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog
       Destination: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_site
      Generating... 
                    done.
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> checking if file toasttoast123 is still present

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123 
ls: cannot access _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123: No such file or directory
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> creating backup for _config.yml before modification

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ 
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ cp -p _config.yml _config.yml.somebackup
```

> adding exclude and keep_files directives and comparing edited file with backup

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ rvim _config.yml
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ diff -u _config.yml _config.yml.somebackup 
--- _config.yml 2016-01-30 09:44:26.238366056 +0200
+++ _config.yml.somebackup  2016-01-30 09:40:08.422370474 +0200
@@ -10,6 +10,3 @@
 # Build settings
 markdown: kramdown
 permalink: pretty
-
-exclude: [someFolderHere]
-keep_files: [someFolderHere]    
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> creating someFolderHere and dummy toasttoast123 file again

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ mkdir _site/someFolderHere
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ touch _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123
```

> running build

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ jekyll build
Configuration file: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_config.yml
            Source: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog
       Destination: /home/wolf/blogs/dummy-blog/_site
      Generating... 
                    done.
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```

> checking if file is still there

```
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ ll _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123 
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolf wolf 0 Jan 30 09:45 _site/someFolderHere/toasttoast123
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$ 
wolf@sloth:~/blogs/dummy-blog$
```