# Jekyll build removing folders even after exclusion; throwing Build Warning about posts

Tags: build, compiler-errors, jekyll, config

I'm trying to set up a folder in my output path that won't be removed when I Jekyll build or serve. As per the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029082/jekyll-clobbering-directory-in-site-despite-config-yml) I tried adding the name of the folder into my _config.yml with both keep_files and exclude, as below:

```
exclude: ["LICENSE", "README.md", "CONTRIBUTING", "CONTRIBUTORS", "scripts", stuff]
keep_files: [stuff]
```

I've tried putting stuff in quotes as well, but so long as I have that in my config attempting to build keeps throwing a Build Warning for each of my posts for some reason.

```
$ Jekyll Build
Configuration file: none
            Source: /home/egrodo/noahyamamoto.com/_posts
       Destination: /home/egrodo/noahyamamoto.com/_posts/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in 2015-06-12-timeline-tutorial.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in 2015-06-19-writing-posts.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in 2015-06-20-blog-tutorial.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in 2015-06-25-initial-setup.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in 2017-03-29-synonym.md does not exist.
                    done in 0.068 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/egrodo/noahyamamoto.com/_posts'
Configuration file: none
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Afterwards, my specified "stuff" folder still exists, but the site isn't built.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well uh, not sure what happened, but I edited an unrelated partial and the error went away and I was able to build successfully whilst keeping the stuff folder. Not sure about this one. Will keep this here in case anyone has any solid info.